# input validation using loop

Tags: java, validation, loops, input

A loop in my class is not returning the expected value. It should return true when the value entered in the method is equal to one of the values in the area.
When I compile and run my main method:
"Please enter the id number to be checked"
I enter 2
"you entered a number for the id"
"565"
"456"
"342"
"234"
"237"
"192"
"237"
"109"
"278"
"num u entered 2 true"
"The value you entered is false"
"Press any key to continue . . ."

The "num u entered 2 true" line is useless, and was just used for testing.
Since 2 is not equal to any of the elements equal in the array, im not sure why it would 
remain false.

Here is my class.

```
public class Account
{
  int[] aNum = {565, 456, 342, 234, 237, 192, 237, 109, 278};
  boolean flag = false;

  public boolean aChecker(int num)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < aNum.length; i++)
    {
      if(num == aNum[i]);
      {
        System.out.println(aNum[i]);
        flag = true;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("num u entered " + num + " " + flag);
    return flag;
  }

}
```

Here is my main method.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class labBookFiftyThree {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Account myAccounts = new Account();

    int id = -1;
    while (id < 0) {
      System.out.println("Please enter the id number to be checked");
      if (myInput.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("you entered a number for the id");
        id = myInput.nextInt();
      } else if (myInput.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a proper value");
        myInput.next();
      } else {
        System.err.println("No more input");
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("The value you entered is " + myAccounts.aChecker(id));
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `System.out.println("The value you entered is "+myAccounts.aChecker(id));` call is outside the loop.

Comment: I think ```boolean flag = false;``` is in the wrong scope, it should probably be inside the ```aChecker``` function, so it can be reseted to ```false``` on each call.

Comment: I just proposed a format edit. you'll clearly see the incorrect `if` statement ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you put the `;` at the end of the `if` line?  Was it just a typo (your finger slipped), or were you confused by somebody teaching you that all statements had to end with a `;`?  I'm really wondering because I've seen this mistake happen a lot and I'm wondering if there's a flaw in how this is being taught.

Comment: Im stupid, my finger slipped and i added a ;, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(num == aNum[i]);
{
    System.out.println(aNum[i]);

    flag = true;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if(num == aNum[i])
    /* do nothing at all */;
{
    System.out.println(aNum[i]);

    flag = true;
}
```

Because of the extra semicolon after the `if`, the `System.out.println` and `flag = true` are not part of the `if` statement.  Therefore they will be performed whether or not the `if` condition is `true`.

Delete the last semicolon from the `if` line.